# OpenGL glTexStorage2D error 1282 Invalid Operation

Tags: python, opengl

Hi I am trying to render a couple of images on to my HTC Vive device using OpenGl.

I keep getting an error as follows:

> err= 1282, description = 'invalid operation',baseOperation = glTexStorage2D, cArguments= (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 1827L, 2030L,)

And a snippet of my code where the error occurs-

```
    image_right = cv2.imread('./sample.png')
    image_left = cv2.imread('./sample_left.jpg')

    height, width, channels = image_left.shape

    cv2.cvtColor(image_left,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.cvtColor(image_right,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    w, h = self.vr_system.getRecommendedRenderTargetSize()

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.zedTextureID_L);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, w, h);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_left)


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.zedTextureID_R);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, w, h);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_right)


    self.texture_t_left.handle = self.zedTextureID_L
    self.texture_t_right.handle = self.zedTextureID_R
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong? I'd be most grateful for any help.
I can send the rest of my code too but it's quite large....

Comment: Where did you generate `zedTextureID_L` and `zedTextureID_R`?

Comment: oh I did that in my initialisation- `self.zedTextureID_L = glGenTextures(1);` and `self.zedTextureID_R = glGenTextures(1);`

Comment: do you even _have_ support for immutable textures in your context?

Comment: do you mean the required version of OpenGL? I'm on 4.6.0 so it should be ok...?

Comment: Check that `zedTextureID_L` and `zedTextureID_R` are not the same, and that they haven't been modified since their assigment by `glGenTextures(1)`

Comment: Yeah there's nowhere else where they would be modified...and tried only using one of them but still gives the same error...